# React scroll page to the top after transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, window, react-dom

I want my application to go to the top of the page when another page within the site is clicked. I have used the code from: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration and put in a separate file.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

**What I have tried:**

I have placed `<ScrollToTop />` before `<Switch />` and after `<BrowserRouter />`as in the docs (these are in separate files).

Unlike the docs, the `<App />` in my application is in a separate file, so `<ScrollToTop />` is not placed near it.

When I console.log, I see it being hit at the correct instance (when there is a page change), but nothing occurs. I have also looked into many stackoverflow posts concerning the same issue, but I could not incorporate their suggestions.

**What are possible issues:**

Calling **window.scrollTo(0, 0)** outside the function does not seem to work. Are there any **alternatives** to this function?

Is the placement of  `<ScrollToTop />` incorrect? Does it have to be called near the `<App />`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant code you are working with? If possible could you also try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have already gone half the way. You really don't need to create a component for it. You can create a custom hook and place it in your `<App />` and then call it:

```
function App() {

  // Scroll to top on every transition custom hook
  const useScrollToTop = () => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [pathname]);
  };

  useScrollToTop();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      .......
    </div>
  )
}
```

This way whenever you go to a new page, it scrolls to the top of the page.

Comment: Can you expand upon what you mean by "place it in your <App />" when the custom hook is called?

Comment: Is it ok if useEffect hook  is already being used within the function App()? When i add the code above, it does not load the page anymore due to errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Did you delete `<ScrollToTop />` component that you said you have placed before `<Switch />`?

Comment: Yes, I did delete the other component before I added the code above.

Comment: So what are the errors?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location') when calling the useLocation()

Comment: Are you correctly importing 'useLocation' from React-Router in the App component?

Comment: Yes, I do correctly import useLocation. I think the issue is that due to some CSS in my app, window.scrollTo was not working properly. Do you have any suggestions for fixing that?

Comment: The method I have provided should achieve what you're looking for. You first need to provide the relevant code that is causing your problem in your original post so we can see what exactly is causing the problem.